# Getting Some Randam ID when Sending a file using MultipartContent() and HttpClient

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a file via an API. I was able to receive the file in my API, but for some reason I am seeing random ID(could be content id) when I read the content in my API.
Previously I was using seeing info about content type and file info as well. I was using MultipartFormDataContent() at that time, then I switched to MultipartContent(). Now the content type and file info is gone, but I still see the id at the start and end of the content.

Code that I am using to send file

```
                using (var formContent = new MultipartContent())
                {
                    byte[] fileByteArray;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
                    {
                        fileByteArray = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
                    }

                    var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileByteArray, 0, fileByteArray.Length);

                    formContent.Add(content);
                    // Add the file and it's content
                    formContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
                    formContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
                    formContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");

                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var task = Task.Run(() => httpClient.PostAsync("MY_END_POINT", formContent));
                    task.Wait();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
```

Code to read file

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileUpload.FileContent))
{
      string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Any idea on how the id can be removed?
[image]

Comment: It seems like you're trying to remove the boundary for the multipart data. From your description, it sounds like you simply want to send `content`, not `formContent`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yeah you are right, not sure why I was trying to send it as formcontent. sending it as content solved the issue. Thank you.